# Magento 2 automatic token saving

Tags: apex, integration, customsetting, custom-metadata

I would need to reduce the token return calls of Magento 2 from this class.

I would have already thought that I could perform this by going to save and history the token within a custom setting.
and based on a boolean it is possible to go execute the query to go retrieve the previously saved token or in case of Response Status != 200 (problem with the old Token, changed or expired) the new token request will be executed using the REquestV2() method and save the new token in the custom setting so it can be reused

Currently this is my code :

```java
public without sharing class MagentoIntegration {
    public static final String CLASS_NAME = MagentoIntegration.class.getName();

    private static MagentoIntegration instance;

    private final MagentoAPI__mdt magentoAPI;
    private final Map<String, MagentoAPI__mdt> magentoAPIs = new Map<String, MagentoAPI__mdt>();
    private final String accessToken;

    private MagentoIntegration(Boolean tryOldTokens) {
        List<MagentoAPI__mdt> apis = [
                SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Username__c, Password__c, Endpoint__c, DynValueGenderMan__c,
                        DynValueGenderWoman__c, DynValueGenderUnknown__c, GetTokenAPI__c, CustomersAPI__c
                FROM MagentoAPI__mdt
        ];

        for (MagentoAPI__mdt tmpApi : apis) {
            magentoAPIs.put(tmpApi.DeveloperName, tmpApi);
        }

        System.debug('magentoAPIs: ' + magentoAPIs);

        String org = Utils.runningInASandbox() ? 'Sandbox' : 'Production';

        this.magentoAPI = magentoAPIs.get(org);
        system.debug('tryOldToken' +tryOldTokens);
        if(!tryOldTokens){
            this.accessToken = storeTokenInCustomSetting();
            system.debug('accessToken' +accessToken);
        }
        
        if(tryOldTokens){
        this.accessToken = retrieveTokenFromCustomMetadata();
            system.debug('accessToken 2' +accessToken);
        }
    }
    
    public static MagentoIntegration getInstance(Boolean tryOldToken) {
        if (tryOldToken) {
            System.debug('tryOldToken: ' + tryOldToken);
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MagentoIntegration(true);
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('tryOldToken: ' + tryOldToken);
            instance = new MagentoIntegration(false);
        }
        System.debug('instance: ' + instance);
        return instance;
    }

    public String retrieveTokenFromCustomMetadata() {
        String token;
        MagentoTokenss__c  mt2 = MagentoTokenss__c.getInstance('TokenM2');
        system.debug('mt2' +mt2);
        List<MagentoTokenss__c> mcs = MagentoTokenss__c.getall().values();
        system.debug('mcs' +mcs);
        token = mt2.MagentoToken__c;
        system.debug('token' +token);
        return token; 
    }
    
     public String storeTokenInCustomSetting() {
         // Assume you have a custom object called MagentoToken__c with fields Token__c and ExpirationTime__c
         List<MagentoTokenss__c> updateList = new List<MagentoTokenss__c>();
         String updatedToken;
         List<MagentoTokenss__c> tokenRecord = [SELECT Id, MagentoToken__c FROM MagentoTokenss__c WHERE id = 'a0y5t000000RZU8AAO' LIMIT 1];
         system.debug('tokenRecord' +tokenRecord);
         
         for(MagentoTokenss__c mn : tokenRecord){
             mn.MagentoToken__c = requestTokenV2();
             updateList.add(mn);
         }

         update updateList;
         
         for (MagentoTokenss__c m2 : updateList){
             updatedToken = m2.MagentoToken__c;
         }
       
         return updatedToken;
    }

    public String requestTokenV2() {
        JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        jsonGen.writeObjectField('username', this.magentoAPI.Username__c);
        jsonGen.writeObjectField('password', this.magentoAPI.Password__c);
        jsonGen.writeEndObject();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint(this.magentoAPI.Endpoint__c + this.magentoAPI.GetTokenAPI__c);
        req.setBody(jsonGen.getAsString());

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        String accessTokenString = res.getBody().replace('"','');
        
        system.debug('accessTokenString' +accessTokenString);

        return accessTokenString;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public MagentoAPI__mdt getMagento2Api() {
        return magentoAPI;
    }

}
```

however, I have a problem regarding the custom setting itself, as running this code the result of the query is null so the RequestV2() method goes to request a new token but does not make any save and no custom setting is found despite the fact that I had entered as a test a custom setting with a dummy token so that I could later perform the update.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there something I can improve within my code?

The class will then be instantiated and called within an additional class via the GetInstance() method.